# Shell script to write output as the name of the folder it runs

Tags: shell

I have a total of 78 ATAC seq samples from which Im trying to do a peak call .I tried this `batchParallel.pl findPeaks peaks` function but i couldn't find the output what it makes.

So I tried using loop but again the peak file is not written due to incorrect argument usage I guess.

These are my sample directories where i have all the tags

```
SRR2920564  SRR2920565
```

I used homer to make tag directories and now i using it for peakcalling.

here is my command.

```
for d in */ ; do findPeaks $d -style factor -o auto "${d}.txt" ; done
```

I do run the loop it runs successfully each file is written as peak.txt in the respective folder.

What i need is all the peakfile should be written as the directory name.

I asked question [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/10776/peak-calling-using-homer) where i did what i was suggested but it worked but not what i would like to .

Later i tried this

```
 for d in */; do findPeaks ${d} -style factor -o auto ${d}/$(basename $d)_peakFile.txt;done
```

But the result is I'm getting peak.txt in each folder not like Such as if directory is "`SRR2920564`" then my peak file should be written in the same directory as `SRR2920564.txt`

Any suggestion or help would be highly appreciated .